# Can I activate a DLC I bought through Steam on a game I bought through App Store?

Tags: steam, mac-app-store

About a year ago I bought `Rome Total War: 2 Emperor Edition` for my Mac through the App Store. I bought the DLC `Greek States` through Steam. I have an activation key for the DLC but when I enter it on Steam, it says that I need to activate the base game first, but I can't get an activation code for the base game because App Store doesn't give you a code.

Is there a way for me to activate the DLC on App Store or the base game on Steam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't activate the games you bought through App Store on Steam or the DLCs you bought through Steam on App Store, so you'll have to either buy the game on Steam or buy the DLC on App Store.

Comment: So wasted money buying the dlc from steam then?

Comment: @Danny you can refund the DLC with Steam Refunds.

Comment: @Danny if this helped you, please hit the green tick button (when 10 minute wait time passes).

Comment: I forgot to mention, I actually bought the game from gamers gate which then I got a code from them and had to download it with steam, and gamers gate do not give refunds, but thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @Danny hmm, then I'd recommend waiting a few hours (steam winter sale starts in 1 hour and 11 minutes) and buying the game from steam.

Comment: @Danny I edited the question and rewrote it in a way that'll help more people. Note: 10 minute wait time passed, if you are planning to accept this as an answer, you can do so now.